# Can you extend Command classes in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, command

I'm currently working on an application working with Laravel 4. I'm working on building a commenting system and have the basic Commands for doing Create, Update, Delete.

What I'm trying to do next is create commands for the specific objects to which the comments will be attached, for example a Blog Post.

So if my command file is called `CreateCommentCommand` I would like to create another command called `CreatePostCommentCommand`. I would like this newer class to extend the `CreateCommentCommand` and have the `type` hardcoded within.

So for `CreateCommentCommand` I have the following:

```
class CreateCommentCommand extends Command {

    public $commentable_type;
    public $commentable_id;
    public $comment;
    public $user_id;

    public function __construct($commentable_type = null,
                                $commentable_id = null,
                                $comment = null,
                                $user_id = null)
    {
        $this->commentable_type = $commentable_type;
        $this->commentable_id = $commentable_id;
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

}
```

... and for `CreatePostCommentCommand` I have:

```
class CreatePostCommentCommand extends CreateCommentCommand {

    public $commentable_type = 'post';

    public function __construct($commentable_id = null,
                                $comment = null,
                                $user_id = null)
    {
        $this->commentable_id = $commentable_id;
        $this->comment = $comment;
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

}
```

For the Handler I have `CreatePostCommentCommandHandler` which extends `CreateCommentCommandHandler`. However the problem I'm encountering is when it hits the field validators which are part of the `CreateCommentHandler` then it says `$commentable_type` was not supplied.

Comment: Please show us the field validators code that is causing the issue

Comment: The `$command` is missing the field before it even gets to them so that's not the problem. It's more that the underlying `handle` function for `CreateCommentCommandHandler` does not know that the `commentable_type` has been set by the child class.

Comment: Still, without the code that's causing the error it's difficult to help you...

Comment: Curious, did you get this working? i was looking to create something similar where I would have before() and after() functions defined for class that Extends the Command class (to implement simple logging to our db for all commands that are run for all Commands in the common before method). and then have my own Commands that extend that class (would it be as easy as running make:command, then modifying the 'extends Command' to extends 'CustomCommand' similar to your above example... or you still couldn't get that to work?

Comment: I'm currently looking at solving some of this by using a Trait...  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php but it's not working as well as extending the constructor would.

Comment: My problem was solved by making my base class abstract. May not apply here, but could be useful reading.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738140/unable-to-deeply-extend-laravel-artisan-command-with-input-passed-down#55738913