# Unable to deeply extend Laravel Artisan Command with input passed down

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Attempting to create a base command, and then extend it.  Input provided to the extending command doesn't make it down the tree.

**BaseApiClassBuilder.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class BaseApiClassBuilder extends Command
{
    // rest of class follows...
}
```

**MakeApiCollection.php**

```
class MakeApiCollection extends BaseApiClassBuilder
{

    protected $signature = 'make:apicollection {name} {--namespace=}';

    protected $description = 'Make an API Collection/Resource';

    // guts of class...
}
```

**Console Command I am running**

```
artisan make:apicollection testApiCollection
```

**Console Error Recieved:**

> The command defined in "App\Console\Commands\BaseApiClassMaker" cannot
>   have an empty name.

Similar question to [Can you extend Command classes in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409489/can-you-extend-command-classes-in-laravel) but that one is a bit out of date and less specific, and also unanswered.

The error only occurs when I extend my base command, instead of 'command'.

I've determined that the validation isn't called in the constructor, it's actually quite tricky to figure out where the input is being validated, and why it isn't making it all the way down.

No doubt I'm doing something goofy and there's an easy solution... but I can't find it!

I anyone can help me understand this better, comments/answers/feedback very gratefully received.  If I'm approaching this completely the wrong way, let me know too.  I did notice I could have extended `GeneratorCommand` instead which has many of the helpers I need, but doesn't seem to solve this problem.

Comment: Cant reproduce. Made a BaseCommand and ChildCommand, entered your signature in the BaseCommand and finally run make:apicollection myName. Works fine, the child class method handle() can access parameters. Can you add any relevant content of your child class? How do you override the signature in the child classes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By making the parent class abstract you don't need to define the `signature`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

abstract class BaseCommand extends Command
{
    ...
}
```

Later in child class you set the `signature` as needed

```
class ChildCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:apicollection {specific-name} {--namespace=}';
```

Comment: Thanks, I pasted it the wrong way around. Editing the question!

Comment: I'm going to try this from a bare-bones perspective with a class that does nothing, and add things until it breaks. I'll let you know how I go. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: looks like abstract might be the key here - otherwise Artisan registers the base class as a command in itself.